# Julia: fail to compile ImageView.jl from JuliaPro 1.1.1.1 (although it runs without problem in Julia 1.1)

Tags: image-processing, julia

I'm running on MacOS `10.14.5`, and I'm trying to use the Package `ImageView.jl` on the freshly installed (today: 26.07.2019) `Julia Pro 1.1.1.1`. After installing `ImageView` without error message, I get the following error message when trying to use the package. The problem doesn't appear when using the Package on `Julia 1.1` (meaning: I can use the Package in Julia 1.1 without problem). I guess that the problem is linked to `Atom` or `Juno`. The following issues are also related on github: [JuliaImages/ImageView.jl#146](https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageView.jl/issues/146) and [JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl#363](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl/issues/363)

```
using ImageView
[ Info: Precompiling ImageView [86fae568-95e7-573e-a6b2-d8a6b900c9ef]
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: error compiling top-level scope: could not load library "libgobject-2.0"
dlopen(libgobject-2.0.dylib, 1): image not found
Stacktrace:
 [1] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at /Applications/JuliaPro-1.1.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 [2] include at ./sysimg.jl:29 [inlined]
 [3] include(::String) at /Users/mymac/.juliapro/JuliaPro_v1.1.1.1/packages/Gtk/aP55V/src/Gtk.jl:2
 [4] top-level scope at none:0
 [5] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at /Applications/JuliaPro-1.1.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 [6] include(::Module, ::String) at /Applications/JuliaPro-1.1.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 [7] top-level scope at none:2
 [8] eval at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [9] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:404
 [10] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /Users/mymac/.juliapro/JuliaPro_v1.1.1.1/packages/Gtk/aP55V/src/GLib/GLib.jl:49
in expression starting at /Users/mymac/.juliapro/JuliaPro_v1.1.1.1/packages/Gtk/aP55V/src/Gtk.jl:7
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Gtk [4c0ca9eb-093a-5379-98c5-f87ac0bbbf44] to /Users/mymac/.juliapro/JuliaPro_v1.1.1.1/compiled/v1.1/Gtk/Vjnq0.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at /Applications/JuliaPro-1.1.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at /Applications/JuliaPro-1.1.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at /Applications/JuliaPro-1.1.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at /Applications/JuliaPro-1.1.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:? (repeats 2 times)
 [5] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at /Applications/JuliaPro-1.1.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 [6] include(::Module, ::String) at /Applications/JuliaPro-1.1.1.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 [7] top-level scope at none:2
 [8] eval at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [9] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:404
 [10] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /Users/mymac/.juliapro/JuliaPro_v1.1.1.1/packages/ImageView/1uiRS/src/ImageView.jl:5
ERROR: Failed to precompile ImageView [86fae568-95e7-573e-a6b2-d8a6b900c9ef] to /Users/mymac/.juliapro/JuliaPro_v1.1.1.1/compiled/v1.1/ImageView/4mtgY.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1197
 [2] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:960
 [3] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:858
 [4] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:853
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the answer is to pin glib 2.58.3, see https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Cairo.jl/issues/271#issuecomment-476827465 (with most users seeming to report it fixes the problem for them).